# Get input of textfield

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, textfield

I have an *textfield* in *Sencha Touch 2* and a button. I would like to get the input of the *textfield* when button is pressed. I tried it with Ext.ComponentQuery, but it didn't work. Have someone an example how to do that?

```js
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    cls: 'inputfields',
    id: 'title',
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    ui: 'action',
    name: 'textfieldButton',
    handler : function(){
        // what should go here ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of writing Sencha Touch 2 in the title, add a sencha-touch-2 tag. Then it's easier to find for Sencha Touch 2 helpers.

Answer (score 4):

My way of doing it is `Ext.getCmp('title').getValue();`

Also please refer to the Docs ([Docs API](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-method-getValue)). They are really Helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```js
var value = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#title')[0].getValue();
// test by writing in console
console.log(value);
```

**TIP 1:** It's helpful to have [API reference](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api) of Sencha open all the time when you use this framework (likewise for any other framework, programming language etc.). For speed, I suggest downloading it.
**TIP 2:** In Chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for developer tools; you can access console there.

Comment: It worekd! Thank you so much.

Comment: +1 for the tips. Though I would suggest working with itemIds instead of ids in order to avoid id conflict with Ext.ComponentManager.